# How can I configure mapstruct to map bidirectional relationships while respecting non-nullable fields?

Tags: kotlin, jpa, mapstruct

I have to entities in a one-to-many relationship. I would like to map DTOs to them while respecting the non-nullable reference on the many side. However, I'm uncertain how to accomplish this with mapstruct.

I have the following DTOs:

```
data class PointInTimeWriteDTO(
    val title: String,
    val note: String,
    val symptoms: Set<SymptomDTO>
)
```

```
data class SymptomDTO (
    val category: String,
    val symptom: String,
    val strength: Strength
)
```

That should be mapped to the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "point_in_time")
class PointInTime(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val note: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "symptom")
    val symptoms: Set<Symptom>
) {
    @field:Column(updatable = false)
    val createdAt: Instant = Instant.now()
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "symptom")
@IdClass(SymptomId::class)
class Symptom(
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "point_in_time_id", nullable = false)
    var pointInTime: PointInTime,
    @Id
    val category: String,
    @Id
    val symptom: String,
    val strength: Strength
)
```

Currently, my mapper is configured as follows:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.WARN)
abstract class PointInTimeMapper {
    abstract fun toBean(pointInTimeWriteDTO: PointInTimeWriteDTO): PointInTime
    abstract fun toSymptomBean(symptomDTO: SymptomDTO): Symptom
}
```

This obviously results in a null pointer exception, since the mapper tries to set `Symptom.pointInTime` to null.

I would like to configure mapstruct in such a way that `PointInTime` is mapped without `symtomps`, which are mapped afterwards with a reference to the `PointInTime` and then added to the same.

What would be the most concise way to write this with mapstruct?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the `NullValueCheckStrategy`. This would tell MapStruct when to check for `null` before settings something.

You can set this using `@Mapper(nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)`

Using `NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS` MapStruct is going to do a `null` check always before setting a field value. This can also be configured on a single `@Mapping` as well.